# What's the principle of uniform_sampling in PCL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, point-cloud-library

Uniform sampling algorithm: The uniform sampling filters the point cloud by constructing a sphere with a specified radius, and the point closest to the center of the sphere in each sphere is output as the point after downsampling.
Voxel filtering is to build a cube, uniform sampling is to build a ball.
My question is how to divide space by building balls? This will cause some space to be missed.

https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_uniform_sampling.html#details

Comment: (In standart eucdiean space with the standart distance-function) You can't, Either the spheres overlap or there is space left out between them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing

Comment: The goal of the operation is to remove points, so it's okay to "miss some space"

Comment: @Stef Why not use cubes?​ Cubes won't miss information, don't they?

Comment: @Wenllshapion You'd have to read the documentation in detail, they probably explain the difference somewhere. I'm guessing the sphere sampling is equivalent to a dodecahedron sampling, and the voxel sampling is equivalent to cubic sampling, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: There's also the question of how efficient the sampling algorithm is depending on how the pointcloud is stored in memory; "find points within radius R of centre C" is maybe more efficient than "find points within square S" depending on the pointcloud data structure (which could be a simple unordered list of points, or a list of points in some logical spatial order, or a mesh, or an octree, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from where you get idea with the sphere/ball. PCL's UniformSampling, just like the VoxelGrid filter, constructs a 3D grid of cubes/voxels. No space is missed. The main difference between UniformSampling and VoxelGrid is that the UniformSampling represents all points in a voxel with the point that is closest to the voxel center, while VoxelGrid computes the mean of all points in a voxel.

Comment: I am not really sure. I did not read the source code but I found that one of the parameters is setRadiusSearch.  Radius are usually used to describe spheres, so I have this question.